# How to find list of messages published on particular topic?

Tags: ros, gazebo, turtlebot, messages, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using turtlebot in gazebo which uses "scan" message for publishing laser scan data, by using `rostopic type scan` command I can find out type of the message i.e. `sensor_msgs/LaserScan` , Is there way to find names of all the messages published on particular topic ?

For example, Is there any way to find out that message named "scan" is published by turtlebot knowing only the topic name i.e. `sensor_msgs/LaserScan` ?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/235695/how-to-find-list-of-messages-published-on-particular-topic?/) by [siddhesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26663/siddhesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 39 on 2016-05-31

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) on 2016-05-31**:
I'm a little confused. Scan is the topic name, sensor_msgs/LaserScan is the message type. Are you asking if there is a way to search for topic names based on message type?

**Comment by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) on 2016-05-31**:
Also, only one type of message can be published to a particular topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are trying to do what I think you are, find all of the topics publishing or subscribing sensor_msgs/LaserScan messages, then the answer is yes. Enter `rostopic find sensor_msgs/LaserScan` in a terminal window and it will list the topics using the sensor_msgs/LaserScan message.

---

Originally posted by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) with karma: 955 on 2016-05-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [siddhesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26663/siddhesh/) on 2016-05-31**:
@Icehawk : Thanks. That's exactly what I needed. Sorry for poor wording.

**Comment by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) on 2016-06-01**:
Not a problem. The nomenclature takes a bit of getting used to. Every time I write a paper or document about ROS the first section is always a glossary :P